# Applying Theorem of dominated convergence (Lebesgue) on this task, possible?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

a) $1<p<\infty, \,M\in\mathbb R,\,\,f,f_j\in L_p(\mathbb R^n)$ and $||f_j||_p\leq M \,\,\forall j$ and $f_j \rightarrow f$ almost everywhere. Proove: Then we have $||f||_p \leq M$.          If $||f_j||_p=M$, then does it follow that $||f||_p=M$?

b) $f\in L_1(\mathbb R^n)$. Proove that: $\forall \epsilon > 0 \,\,\exists E \subset \mathbb R^n$ measurable with $\lambda^n(E)<\infty: \,\,\,\int_{\mathbb R^n - E} |f| d\lambda^n<\epsilon$

c) $p,q \in (1,\infty),\,\,1/p + 1/q = 1, \,\,f,f_j\in L_p(\mathbb R^n),\,\,M\in\mathbb R$ with $||f_j||_p \leq M\,\,\forall j$ and $f_j \rightarrow f$ almost everywhere. Proove: $\lim_{j\rightarrow\infty} \int_{\mathbb R^n} f_j \,g \,\,d\lambda^n = \int_{\mathbb R^n} f \,g \,\,d\lambda^n$

---

For a) and b) I don't get an idea how to proove that nor can I find a counter example.

---

And c) I'm sure you have to apply the Hölder inequality and then use Lebesgue. But I just don't see how applying Hölder helps us to find a majorant in $L_1$ we need to apply Lebesgue.

Comment: For (a), use Fatou's lemma. For (b), start by assuming $f$ is a simple function and work up from there. What is $g$ in (c)?

Comment: IT IS SPELLED "PROVE" NOT "PROOVE." Getting that out of the way: For the example in (a) you can consider the indicator of the segment $[n, n+1].$ For (b) note that $g_n = f \mathbf{1}_{\mathrm{K}_n}$ (where $\mathrm{K}_n$ is a ball of radius $n$) satisfies $|g_n| \leq |f| \in \mathscr{L}^1$ and $g_n \to f$ a.s. In (c), is $g \in \mathscr{L}^q$?

Comment: (In (c), if $g \in \mathscr{L}^q$ you just need to copy the proof of the dominated convergence theorem; in other words, apply Fatou's lemma to both $f_j g$ and $-f_j g.$)